# Fragment replace doesn't work always

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This is my situation:

I have several fragments added dynamicly to an FragmentStatePagerAdapter, this works fine. But now i want to be able to replace an fragment when I push on an button.

```
public class QuestionFragment extends UpperFragment {

      ...

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setRetainInstance(true);
    CustomViewPager.enabled = true;

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, container, false);

    Button btn = ((Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bQuestion));

    if (how == true) {
        btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // lijst afgaan met alle how en kijken welke id nodig is

                for (int i = 0; i < XmlParserSax.howFragments.size(); i++) {
                    Fragment how = XmlParserSax.howFragments.get(i);

                    if (howId.equals(((UpperFragment) how).getIdNum())) {

                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction();
                        transaction
                                .replace(R.id.flQuestion, how, "howFragment")
                                .setTransition(
                                        FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
                        break;

                    }

                }

            }
        });
    } else {
        btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

So when i press the button the current layout (R.id.flQuestion) is replaced with the new fragment. This works, but the tricky part comes here:

When I slide to the next fragment and the slide to the fragment with the button it keeps working but if i slide 2 times to the next fragment (of the same type QuestionFragment) it does the functionallity of the new fragment but it doesn't show the new fragment.. So it seems that it can't replace the R.id.flQuestion because it is stored in memory maybe?

I need to be sure that the fragment is always replaced even if the next 2 fragments are of the same type and same layout (R.id.flQuestion)..

This is the class layout of the new frag

```
public class HowFragment extends UpperFragment {
 ..
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setRetainInstance(true);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.how, container, false);

    //if back key pressed return to layout of Question
    rootView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); //this line is important
    rootView.requestFocus();
    rootView.setOnKeyListener( new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
        {
            if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
            {
                CustomViewPager.enabled = true;
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    } );

    //don't allow pushing button again
    rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;

        }

    });



    return rootView;
}
```

Also important to tell: i'm using framelayouts for both the fragments (so no hard coded fragment tag in the xml)

To make it clear:
This happens when the next fragment is from different class, no problem
[image: normal]

This happens when next fragments are from the same layout and class:
[image: problem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll have to test the code, but from what I see, easiest way to make this work is to grab new Fragment even if it is the same fragment class.

> Fragment how = XmlParserSax.howFragments.get(i);

If this function is returning new instance of a fragment, it should work.

Hope that helps

Edit :

I'm pretty sure the activity can access the button after the fragments are created. 
Otherwise you need a handler to pass the click to handle it in the adapter. I'm seeing the your list of fragments are static (Not recommended). Since you haven't added any codes for how you setup the pageradapter, I have no idea what list you are using, but you need to change out the item in that list. From the Activity where you initialized the pager, you can call the public function to replace the current pager item pager. (you can use ViewPager.getCurrentItem())

I haven't tested, so you might have to tweak and play around to perfect it.

Hope this helps.

Here is a sample :

> ```
>  public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
>   ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentArray = new ArrayList<Fragment();
>    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
>        super(fm);
>    }
>
>    //didn't put in the function to populate the list with fragments
>
>   public void replaceItem(Fragment newFrag, int pos){
>        fragmentArray.remove(pos);
>        fragmentArray.add(pos,newFrag);
>        notifyDataSetChanged();
>   }
>
>
>   @Override
>    public int getCount() {
>        return fragmentArray.size();
>    }
>
>    @Override
>    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
>        return fragmentArray.get(position);
>    }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: hmm I think I don't understand what you mean, maybe I also forgot to tell that i'm getting the How fragment from an list with only how fragments.. This is because I need the correct fragment How in the correct fragment Question (because there are different questions with different hows)

Comment: Perhaps you are missing a notifydatasetchanged()? I'm understanding that statepager is used to swipe between fragment and a button to open a new fragment. This means that since you are on a viewpager already, you can instead replace the current viewpager item to be whatever fragment you desire and just call the notifydatasetchanged to update the adapter.

Comment: hmm that sounds like a good idea, where should i put the notifydatasetchanged()? then? maybe you could give me an example because i can't acces the adapter from the class i think?

Comment: I've tried that and what it is doing now is the following:   when i push the button nothing happnes only when i swipe 2 fragments further and swipe then back it has changed, so it looks like the notifydatasetchanged() does not work?  And maybe an disadvantage of doing it like this is that when i press the back button it doesn't change to the original fragment wich is the intention?

Comment: Okey so far for the notifydatasetchanged().. it was a bug, fix it with   @Override
 public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
  return POSITION_NONE;
 }

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19001

Comment: Yep No problem. I forgot to mention about that one bug, notifydatasetchanged() is kinda buggy with pageradapter ;P anyway glad you got everything working!